# Connected to wifi, no ping to router

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I have **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64** installed in a **Dell Inspiron 15 5000**. Everything was fine, until recently that I booted it up. It had no battery so it turned off while booting. After that, I can’t access Internet.
I am connected to the router.

`ping localhost` 0% packet loss

`ping -c3 192.168.1.1` 100% packet loss

`ping -c3 192.168.100.1` 0% packet loss

`ping 8.8.8.8` does not work at all

I tried resetting the network via

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I also tried turning off and on the router and the laptop, but it is still not working.

Strangely, [the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFN9z.jpg) indicates that I am connected to the wifi, but the top bar says otherwise.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Update: it was the kill switch from ProtonVPN the issue, I deactivated it using

```
protonvpn-cli ks --off
```

Comment: Great. You can accept your own answer in 2 days by clicking the V shaped sign on the left of the answer. That will give you 15 reputation points if I am correct.